# What is the word for a person who destroys monuments?

Tags: single-word-requests

About 20 years ago, I had a book that was definitions of colorful, interesting, unusual, and oddly specific words. One of the words described someone who engaged in (and possibly enjoyed, but I don't remember) the act of destroying or vandalizing monuments.

Comment: Are you sure it was _exclusively_ monuments?

Comment: I'm absolutely positive.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. Perhaps identifying the book would help [here's some guidelines from Scifi SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) which might help

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately, the only thing I remember about the book is this specific word I'm looking for and its definition. Aside from that, the only extra information I can give is that it had a sort of sepia color palette with a line illustration on the front.

Comment: Look around for it and tell us what you found. Good Luck.

Comment: Might it have been a satirical/humorous dictionary composed of made up words or cynical definitions? Like, say, "Devil's Dictionary" by Ambrose Bierce?

Comment: The other kris here.   Monumental a..holes. Is one term for this

Comment: The Meaning of Tingo, perhaps?

Comment: I think you need to specify exactly what sort of monument you mean.  It could be any number of things: a gravestone, a memorial plaque, an ancient building (or a not-so-ancient one erected to honor a person, e.g. Washington Monument), even (in the US) an area of land of some special interest ("National Monument").  Even Monument Valley: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_Valley

Comment: re: humorous dictionary, I was thinking "Petricide" sounded like a Sniglet - (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglet ).  I read those books (collections of them)  when I was a kid, so I often think of those words as just as "real" as any other.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was able to find the following:

> Antivitruvian (adj): Taking pleasure in destroying architectural monuments.

From "Insulting English" by Peter Novobatzky and Ammon Shea, page 12.

Comment: Yes! This was exactly it! That was the book I read as well. You got everything spot on. Thank you!

Comment: @ianrandmckenzie Happy to help!

Comment: Ohhh great word! I love it!

Comment: Is this "antivitruvian" or "anti-vitruvian"? Most usages (Google search) seem to be the latter...

Comment: @CJBS I copied it from the book, so I don't know (I'm not an expert in this field). Was just trying to find the word OP was asking for :)

Answer (score 62):

Could you perhaps mean **iconoclast**? Historically, this means a person who destroys images in religious buildings because they see them as idols. The meaning has been extended to include people who attack (physically or otherwise) respected objects or cherished beliefs.

Comment: A good one, but I don't recall there being religious attachments to the word.

Comment: Not all monuments are images.

Comment: @ianrandmckenzie Historically, yes; for example Puritans in 17th century England.

Comment: The origins of this word certainly have their roots in religion, but today the word is used *far* more widely than just those who object to *religious* monuments—probably for lack of a good alternative. This answer would be improved by noting that, particularly considering the @ianrandmckenzie’s comment.

Comment: Not all iconoclasts destroy things. They merely eschew images of them. So, this answer is inaccurate.

Comment: These days the word is used much more to refer to people who attack or eschew popular beliefs or institutions, not usually specific to physical defacement.

Comment: @Lambie A trip to dictionary.com yields "a breaker or destroyer of images, especially those set up for religious veneration."

Comment: @Casey monuments are not images. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Lambie What is a "graven image" if not a kind of monument?

Comment: @Lambie You might also consult [this definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/image), which affirms that "an image is a representation as in a statue or effigy, and is sometimes regarded as an object of worship."

Answer (score 26):

There is [Petracide](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-petracide) which is the destruction of ancient stone buildings or monuments (but not necessarily the vandalising of them).

From *The Wordsworth Book of Intriguing Words* (P. Hellweg, 1986)

Comment: That's why I included the reference to my source.

Comment: Not to be confused with patricide ...

Comment: This seems to ring a bell. I'll keep trying to find the book it was in and hopefully confirm this at some point. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin always good to know there’s no middle-man changing the definitions of words!

Comment: @ianrandmckenzie This is an artificial coinage that is *surpassingly* unlikely to have been something you read just about *anywhere*, since it’s not “really” a word. Google fails to find any usages in its [corpus of books from the last two centuries](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=petracide&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), for example.

Comment: Great word for a _stone_ cold killer.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Cute pun but you're more right than you intend: It's *only* a word for a stone killer. There's no reason this nonceword would reference monuments or buildings or even destroyer. It's simply literal New Latin for 'stone-killer'. ***Iconoclast* is actually the right word here, even if it isn't what OP was trying to remember.**

Comment: @KRyan See the New York Times, February 3, 1985, Section 4, Page 20: https://www.nytimes.com/1985/02/03/opinion/topics-gratuitous-insults-petracide.html So it was coined by the NYT article, but the repeated in the Jerusalem Post, Robertson's Words for the Modern Age, this scientific article http://sa.agr.hr/pdf/2008/sa2008_0544.pdf , and a few other places

Answer (score 8):

Merriam-Webster:

A [vandal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vandal) is someone who willfully or ignorantly destroys, damages, or defaces property belonging to another or to the public.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking specifically for the word that includes the context of monuments.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandalism_of_art

Answer (score 8):

Pretty sure "iconoclast" is the only applicable word.

It's possible to cobble together any word you want, in English, by sticking Greek or Latin roots together. Sometimes people do that for amusement purposes. Is that what your book was? If there were a generally-used word for that, it surely wouldn't be so hard to find!

Besides Ambrose Bierce's, "The Meaning Of Liff" is another one of those comedy dictionaries from the early 1980s. Douglas Adams wrote it. It gives place names in the UK funny definitions as if they were real words. It was popular back then, maybe that's what you're remembering?

Comment: Doesn't this only apply to religious artifacts?

Comment: I suppose technically it does. I just don't think there's a better word, applicable to all statuary, etc.

Comment: @KennethK. No, if you check the dictionary you'll see that's not true.

Comment: @Casey [I did](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclast), but thanks.

Comment: @KennethK. Ethimologically  speaking, _iconoclastic_ does not refer to religious artifacts. The religious connection is probably due to [Byzantine Iconoclasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Iconoclasm).

Comment: @KennethK. [This definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/iconoclast?s=t) does not confine it to religious images

Answer (score 6):

"***Desecrator***" should work in this context -

## Desecrator

> (*plural* desecrators)
>
> : A person who [profanes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/profane) or violates the [sacredness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sacred) or [sanctity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sanctity) of
> something.

([Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desecrator))

Here, "*something*" can refer to any monument or building in general.

---

The *verb* form would be -

## Desecrate

> - treat (a sacred place or thing) with violent disrespect.
> - spoil (something which is valued or respected).

Answer (score 4):

**Idoloclast**

A ‘breaker of idols’.

I looked up ‘clast’ and it means ‘a fragment of rock’.

So I looked up ‘words ending in clast’ and I found ‘idoloclast’ - someone who breaks idols.

Hope this is the word you want, as a monument is ‘statue, building, or other structure erected to commemorate a famous or notable person or event.’ Which is kind of like an ‘idol’ (although we may not worship it!)  ‘Monument’ did previously include the meaning ‘effigy’ (now obsolete), by the way.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monument

Example: ‘the idoloclasts are smashing up the ancient petroglyphs’.

As an aside, smashing cultural heritage has now been included as a war crime. Although, often after wars, many idolatrous statues (eg of tyrants) created by regimes, are taken down. There are whole articles on that, online.

Idoloclast:
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idoloclast

Another nice ‘clast’ word is ‘mythoclast’ - a decrier of myths. I’m going to remember that one!

I did find ‘idoloclast’ mentioned in ‘Putnam’s word book’

https://archive.org/stream/putnamswordbookp00flemrich/putnamswordbookp00flemrich_djvu.txt

There is also ‘idoloclasm’:
https://books.google.co.id/books?id=_-GEDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT255&lpg=PT255&dq=idoloclasm&source=bl&ots=MZcgSqXxCr&sig=ACfU3U3G_GVyqto5nPpwawNeEcgCIBX0iQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOn7vClNbkAhXQXisKHQ8oBn4Q6AEwDnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=idoloclasm&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Given that *-cide* means *kill*, and *-clast* means *something that breaks*, the word should be neither *petracide* nor *iconoclast* but **petraclast**: a breaker of rocks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98950/discussion-on-answer-by-ronjohn-what-is-the-word-for-a-person-who-destroys-monum).

Answer (score 1):

Its not a single word, but a term often used to metaphorically describe someone who specifically attempts to destroy a monument or work of art is "Laszlo Toth".

This is the name of a deranged individual who [took to Michelangelo's  Pietà with a sledgehammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laszlo_Toth) in 1971.

For something that isn't quite as specific, but is a single word, I'd agree with the other answers that suggest "iconoclast". Literally, that word is meant to indicate someone who destroys religious iconography. Its more often these days used more metaphorically to indicate a person that attacks things others hold sacred. The implication is usually that the thing in question is revered for no good reason, other than that it always has been, and the "iconoclast" is doing everyone a favor.

By comparison, calling someone a Laszlo Toth generally indicates they are being destructive of valuable things that would be difficult or impossible to replace for no real good reason.

Comment: A Google search for "a Laszlo Toth" gives only 1400 results; I've checked the first 30, and only one can even be considered as relevant ("a Laszlo Toth complex").

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I usually hear it used as either an overt metaphor, or occasionally even a simile. For example, I can remember hearing comedian Dennis Miller using it in routines at least twice (although he is rather famous for using super obscure references. Here's a [third](https://omny.fm/shows/the-dennis-miller-option/s2-e59-chappelles-special-us-open-cnns-climate-cha?in_playlist=the-dennis-miller-option!podcast) I was unaware of).

Comment: I'd rather remember Michelangelo and forget ... er....

Comment: I have never seen criminals names used to name a type of destruction, except maybe on TV crimes shows quoting medical literature...

Comment: Cf. [Don Novello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Novello), who wrote subversive letters to various prominent people using the *nom de plume* "Lazlo Toth."

Comment: @Robusto - Yes, his book "The Lazlo Letters" was where I first came across the name. It was kind of like morning radio DJ crank calling politicians, but with mail.

Comment: [Here's a better intro to the attack than the Wiki article](https://markdemers.wordpress.com/tag/laszlo-toth/). I don't think I can show a photo in these comments, but here's the image of the Pieta after the attack: [https://markdemers.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/may-25-pieta.jpg](https://markdemers.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/may-25-pieta.jpg). He got off the nose, broke an eye, and dropped her left arm, shattering its hand.

Comment: I'm giving you a vote just for being interesting!